# How to hide certain routes from public access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am working on an app on Rails 4 and using devise with a custom Registrations controller. I am redirecting users to a certain route after they sign up but before they confirm their email.

However, this route is defined in the routes file and is accessible publicly. Is there any way to make this route private, so that it can only be reached through the application controller? Or maybe some alternate way of rendering a view without defining a route to it?

Comment: You can use _authorization_ to prevent access to the page by unwanted users.

Comment: @sevenseacat As far as I understand, using `authorized` would mean that only signed in users would be able to access that route, however when a user has registered, he isn't signed in as he needs to confirm the email. So it would not solve the problem at all.

Comment: no, you can do authorization any way you like, eg. setting a session var or cookie when the user registers, and authorizing against that.

Comment: Okay, I will try that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write routes for request-response cycle and each request is passes through application controller.

If you want dont want to give access to particular routes, you can use **before_filter** in application controller as,

```
before_filter :restrict_use

def restrict_user
 unless current_user.allowed?
   redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

It will work in same manner as devise's **before_filter :authenticate_user!** method

Answer (score 0):

```
   before_action
```

And then redirect logic, or read about

```
   hide_action
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/hide_action/class